# How to list columns with corresponding indices in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to display a list of all of my pandas data frame column names with the corresponding indices.

This is to get a consecutive list of indices for a later `.iloc` operation. I have tried `pd.columns` but this doesn't list indices.

```py
data.columns
```

Output:

```py
Index(['Respondent ID', 'Collector ID', ...
```

Excpected Output:

```py
Index([[0] -> 'Respondent ID', [1] -> 'Collector ID', ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Something like `dict(enumerate(df.columns))`?

Comment: @Chris: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension with `enumerate` and `f-strings`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=['Respondent ID', 'Collector ID'], index=[0])

data.columns = [ f'[{i}] -> {x}' for i, x in enumerate(data.columns)]

print (data)
   [0] -> Respondent ID  [1] -> Collector ID
0                     0                    0
```

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by Chris, this is the simplest and most readable solution:

```
dict(enumerate(df.columns))
```